# What is the most cost effective approach to connect a Lambda to a kafka topic in AWS MSK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-msk

I'd like to attach a Lambda function to a topic in a AWS MSK Kafka cluster, but it is not possible yet, from what I understood in AWS docs.

So I thought I could have a Lambda function that will run in a interval basis, using a CloudWatch event to trigger it each minute.

Another option is to run a small ec2 unit to run the client consumer.

I'm not sure if that's the cheapest solution. So what are the most cost effective solutions we could use to implement a solution that will work like a Lambda to SQS connector?

Answer (score 1):

You can now use an MSK topic as an event source for AWS lambdas (as of last week)! This service comes at no additional cost per the release statement amazon sent out!

Once you create your lambda function, you can add MSK as a trigger. Make sure you attach the appropriate policies (as outlined in the article referenced below).

Here are a few relevant resources.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-msk-as-an-event-source-for-aws-lambda/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-msk.html